# Set identifier of table cell view programmatically

Tags: cocoa, swift3, nstableview, macos-sierra

I have table view like this (in a mac cocoa application):

[image]

In the leftmost panel you can see that I have set the identifier of the `Table Cell View` to "1". That's fine if you just have 2 columns, once the number goes up, this approach will become cumbersome. Can I do this programmatically?

Here is an example:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

private var dataModel = DataModel()
private var answer = 0
private var keyData: (Int, [Int]) = (0, []) {
    didSet {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var questionIndex: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tbl: NSTableView!
@IBAction func replay(_ sender: Any) {
    dataModel = DataModel()
    questionIndex.stringValue = "0:"
    answer = 0
    updateModel()
}

@IBAction func forward(_ sender: NSButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        answer += keyData.0
    }
    updateModel()
}

func updateModel() {
    let group = dataModel.nextGroup()
    if let g = group {
        self.keyData = g
        let s = questionIndex.stringValue
        questionIndex.stringValue = String(Int(String(s.characters.dropLast()))! + 1) + ":"
        return
    }
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = "You did have \(answer) on your mind, didn't you?"
    alert.runModal()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for (n, col) in tbl.tableColumns.enumerated() {
        col.identifier = String(n)
    }
    updateModel()
}

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return keyData.1.count / 8 + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let colId = tableColumn!.identifier
    let colIndex = Int(colId)!
    let index = (row * 8) + colIndex
    let cell = tbl.make(withIdentifier: colId, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
    if 0 <= index && index < keyData.1.count {
        cell.textField!.integerValue = keyData.1[index]
    } else {
        cell.textField!.stringValue = ""
    }
    return cell
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

I have assigned the cell identifiers by hand, and made them identical the corresponding column index, so as to creating a mapping between the cell id and the 2D array (which is the underlying data model) column index. The app is running fine, I just don't like assigning these IDs by click-and-point.

The full project can be found here: https://github.com/kindlychung/MysteriousNum

Comment: Identifiers are not normally used to indicate index, but rather a "type" of cell that can appear in your table. Like "GroupCell" or "ItemCell".

Comment: Yeah, although it could also be represented with a number. Enum types can be Int, for example. The identifier 1 here is probably a string "1" anyway.

Comment: But that's not the point. The point is **how can I set that identifier programmatically**, to "GroupCell", if you want.

Comment: You mean for an instance of a cell that you already have instantiated?

Comment: I don't know the internals of interface builder or cocoa, a educated guess would be that, given the table view is defined in a storyboard and has an outlet in the view controller, than I should probably be able to reach that cell through the outlet, right? For example, here: https://github.com/kindlychung/MysteriousNum/blob/master/MystieriousNum/ViewController.swift#L22

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish - have you tried running through some of the view-based NSTableView tutorials? If you really want to _programmatically associate a particular NIB with an identifier_ you can do so: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableview/1524297-registernib?language=objc But normally you'll assign the identifiers in Interface Builder, then instantiate them using that _known_ identifier in your code.

Comment: In the above linked project I just manually assigned cell identifier in interface builder, as 0, 1, 2, 3,..., etc. The purpose of this is to make the id function as a column number, which will be convenient when I populate the table with a 2D array. The project is working perfect, btw. I just don't like adding identifiers manually.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through at least two NSTableView tutorials, and the identifiers are manually assigned in both cases.

Comment: You don't need it though - when the table view asks you (its datasource and delegate) for a view, it will _provide you_ with the column number. Take a look at your method signature: `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` You have both the column, and the row.

Comment: Yes, but I need a mapping between the 2D array columns and the Table columns, hence I need a number, not just a NSTableColumn.

Comment: In that case, you can just ask the table view: `let columnIndex = tableView.tableColumns.index(of: tableColumn)`

Comment: Great! There is still a problem, though: https://github.com/kindlychung/MysteriousNum/blob/master/MystieriousNum/ViewController.swift#L66 What's to be used for the `withIdentifier` param?

Comment: You should be using the `colId` like you currently are. Are you running into a specific issue?

Comment: There's a way to  completely get rid of the identifier hassle: Implement `objectValueFor:row:` and use Cocoa Bindings

Comment: @vadian Could you write up an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Create custom cell and add init to it using following lines.

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

and register this cell class as.

```
self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

also dequeueReusableCell using same cell like:

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell",for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
```

Comment: The question is clearly about macOS (***NS**TableView*)

Comment: Question was about osx app programming.

Comment: -1! The above methods apply to UITableViews, *not* NSTableViews. There isn't an obvious "registerCustomCell" method in NSTableView, hence the question.